# Updating Pixel after many months. Will I get all the missing monthly security patches?

Tags: updates, security, ota-update, android-11, google-pixel-4a

**Not** a duplicate of this
[Are security patches only applied to the latest Android version?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230188/131553)

---

I have a Pixel 4a, Android 11, running November security update. For various reasons, I do not wish to apply monthly updates, maybe do it once in a quarter or maybe even more (I know & accept the risk, let's not get into that).

- I know I can update, whenever by [full OTA](https://developers.google.com/android/ota) or [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/images). I prefer the OTA route because

> This (OTA) has the same effect as flashing the corresponding factory image, but without the need to wipe the device or unlock the bootloader.

- Accepted answer here, indicates that I can  update, for example in June 21,without flashing all (7 months) of images, which is good [What is the difference between Factory Images and Full OTA Images on the Android download site?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207600/what-is-the-difference-between-factory-images-and-full-ota-images-on-the-android)

My question now is that **will the June 21 full OTA incorporate all the  intermediate security patches (seven months) ?**

I searched a lot (fairly good at that) but couldn't get a conclusive answer.

I am looking for an answer with credible backing (it may change my update plan).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117705/discussion-on-question-by-beeshyams-updating-pixel-after-many-months-will-i-get).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the chat discussion with Irfan Latif, alecxs and Kulfy the consensus was :

- The OTA update *should* in theory have all previous security patches applied.
- Updates are not covered under AOSP documentation and it's left to OEMs discretion. Probably that's why there isn't documentation around this.
- Therefore, reach out to Google for a conclusive answer.

I chatted with Google and this person had to take help of technical resource. The chat window is tiny but here is the conclusion

[image]

> I've checked this with my resources and would like to inform you that once you've updated your device to the latest security patch so it should cover all the security patch features up till date.

Despite my request they couldn't offer any technical insight in terms of documentation or code,which would have been nice but then I got a credible answer!